# Is there any way to remove the "Back to Safari" button appearing in iOS 9 via code in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I have an app that lets users log in with a facebook account, and through that process I redirect them to the facebook login page which iOS 9 now accomplishes through safari instead of a webview. Now, when my app runs after that happens, I have a permanent "Back to Safari" button at the very top of my app in place of the carrier/wifi signal and on top of some of my buttons.
Is there anything I can do about this? I've been searching online and can't seem to find anything that would let me turn it off.

[image: image desc]

Comment: If you update to the latest FB SDK, it does the login in-app.  And to answer your question: no.

Comment: Also: the button isn't permanent.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no API available to allow you to do this.

This is an iOS 9 feature, and it's what users will come to expect.

If you do find a work around such as covering this part of the status bar, you'll probably be in violation of 10.1 on the [App Store review](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) guidelines and may have your app rejected for it.

Comment: You are correct that once the "Back to Safari" thing is showing, you cannot (and should not try to!) programmatically remove it. However there *is* an API to use Safari *without leaving your app* and thus *never incurring the "Back to Safari" thing in the first place.* (See my answer.)

Comment: There *is* no api for *removing* that functionality. While you do have access to SFSafariViewController as an alternative, the question was about *turning* *off* the 'back to safari' button. I think the latest FBSDK supports not ever even needing to move out to safari anyway.

Comment: He just asks, "Is there anything I can do about this?" There is, and I told him. I mean, it's like when a programmer went to the doctor and he said, "It hurts when I sit like *this.*" <He slumps over horribly like when he's coding.> "What can I do about this problem?" So the doctor said, "Well, for starters, don't sit like that..." <Shows him how to sit up straight.>

Comment: I second @CommaToast The underlying question is "how to get rid of that Safari back link, even better if it doesn't show up in the first place"

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to using [SKSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/). That way the user never leaves your app.

Of course if you want to maintain backwards compatibility with iOS 8 and earlier, you'll have to have separate code for iOS 9, versus earlier versions.

In my app, it was a breeze to use SKSafariViewController, and I never have any kind of issue with the "Back To Safari" thing. That should never happen with SKSafariViewController. If it does, then you're doing it wrong—i.e. somehow you are forcing the user to switch to the actual Safari app, which they should not need to do.

For a good tutorial [see this site](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller--cms-24260), or google .. Apple had a pretty good WWDC'15 video on the subject.

BTW, I am 100% sure this can work for FaceBook logins, because I have seen a major app that uses it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the background you could just cover it with an opaque overlay.

To do that create a new window and set its level above the status bar's.

It's a bit hacky and probably does not remove the interactivity from that area (you can still tap the button). Also it's difficult to know when the button is gone and you have to remove the cover.

So, better not do this.